# Does ADMOB have a blacklist for the applications?

Tags: android, admob

A friend of mine has developed several applications which were simply collections of sexy pictures(no nude). They all received ads normally at the beginning but all stopped to fetch ads after several days.

Some of them stopped after hundreds of requests, while others stopped at 1k/2k request. From the logcat we can see that it is reporting that

```
onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.)
```

but we wait for more than a week it still cannot recover from this problem. And on the ADMOB console we saw that all the related ads are marked as greed point with excalmatory mark saying that the "site has not requested ad for the past 72 hours"

We tried to create a new ad for the same app, but it still reports the same issue.

However, we use the same ad in another test application with different package name, the ad shows normally.

So, I wonder if Google has blacklisted the application. And is there any way to contact the authority of ADMOB to check which rules we have violated so that we can fix it in future.

Comment: Why down vote? Although it is not an obvious programming problem but it might be a technical issue met by several Android/Admob developers. I have Googled this issue and found same problems without solutions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Admob's policies, not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly mentioned in Admob publishing guidelines that it will not allow such apps to show their ads.

Apps having Adult content can't show admob ads.
Below are the items that admob will not consider.

```
Sexually suggestive text, images or situations
Nudity (full, partial or implied)
Prostitution (direct solicitation or implied)
Abortion related advertisements or messaging
```

Initially, They would not have tracked the app, as there are thousands of apps published daily, and it is impossible to verify all the apps for adult content.
Unlike Apple (They have a verification check of each app), google allows developer to publish any app.

But once they verify in a month or so, They will not provide ads to your app.

Comment: Our applications do NOT contain any nudity or prostitution content. Do you mean that 'sexy pictures' are 'sexually suggestive'?

Comment: Yes, That is what admob mean from it.
Give a try to revmob. They dont have any such policy.

If a app is fit to be on Google play, they will serve ads.